# ORA-01732 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 'instructors':

[image]

and a task:

> If the number of courses an instructor teaches is less than 1 then
>   update the salary to 30000 else to 35000 – in one command.

I wrote this code:

```
update (select name, salary, count(course_id) as nm 
        from instructor i 
        left join teaches t on t.id = i.id 
        group by name, salary)
set salary =
case
  when nm < 1 then  30000
  else 35000
end
```

However, it gives error

> ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a [popular homework question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844466/count-function-inside-case-statement/48844585#48844585) these days, eh?

To repeat myself: how about something like this (you might need to adjust column names):

```
update instructor i set
  i.salary = (select case when count(*) < 1 then 30000
                          else 35000
                     end
              from teaches t
              where t.id_instructor = i.id_instructor);
```

Comment: To be fair maybe @alice_schizoid doesn't realise she's already asked the question before (the clue is in the name).